# Comparing consecutive rows using oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, date, sql-delete

I have a table which looks something like this:

```
| ID | FROM_DATE | TO_DATE |
------------------------------
| 1  |  1/1/2001 | 2/1/2001|
| 1  |  2/1/2001 | 3/1/2001|
| 1  |  2/1/2001 | 6/1/2001|
| 1  |  3/1/2001 | 4/1/2001|
| 2  |  1/1/2001 | 2/1/2001|
| 2  |  1/1/2001 | 6/1/2001|
| 2  |  2/1/2001 | 3/1/2001|
| 2  |  3/1/2001 | 4/1/2001|
```

It is already sorted by `ID`, `From_Date`, `To_date`.

What I want to do is delete the rows where the `from_date` is earlier than the `to_date` from the previous line and the ID is equal to the ID from the previous line.  So in this example, I would delete the **3rd** and **6th** rows only.

I know I need some kind of looping structure to accomplish this, but I don't know how since I'm really looking at two rows at a time here.  How can I accomplish this within Oracle?

EDIT: Where using the 'LAG' function is quicker and easier, I end up deleting the **4th** and **7th** rows also - which is not what I want to do.  For example, when it gets to **row 4**, it should compare the 'from_date' to the 'to_date' from **row 2** (instead of row 3, because row 3 should be deleted).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `lag` window function to identify these rows:

```
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE rowid IN (SELECT rowid
                FROM   (SELECT rowid, from_date, 
                               LAG(to_date) OVER 
                                  (PARTITION BY id
                                   ORDER BY from_date, to_date) 
                                  AS lag_to_date
                        FROM   my_table) t
                WHERE  from_date < lag_to_date)
```

Comment: In case you are unfamiliar with the LAG function see the [documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) LAG allows you to access multiple rows at once without using a self join.

Comment: This actually has me deleting more rows than I intended - it deletes rows 4 and 7 also.  I should have been more clear, I want it to go through each row, compare the from_date to the previous to_date, and if it is earlier, delete that row.  I'm going to edit my question to reflect that.

Comment: Scratch my comment - I mistakenly replaced 'rowid' with 'id' when I brought it in.  I didn't realize 'rowid' was special, thank you!

Comment: @mjavon yup, [`rowid`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm) is a pseudocolumn that returns the address of the row. Sort of a built-in primary key, if you will.